# Appropriate separation of concerns for this case?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

This is a method that calls a web service, it uploads an audio file and fetches metadata back.

While the advantage is that there is only one method to call there are a few concerns about it :

- There is some UI-related code (upload progress)
- Some audio-related code (format detection)
- Web-service related code (first purpose)

In the end, while it tries to be smart, it's completely tied to a particular audio library, it will report progress anyway and well, it doesn't only upload ...

How would you apply separation of concerns to this current method ?

- Would transforming the *fileFormat* to a parameter be acceptable ?
- What about *handler*, how can it be used without being tied to the upload process ?

I'm not necessarily asking for code, directions to some documentation on the subject is fine too.

```
public class TrackUpload
{
    public async Task<string> Upload(string apiKey, string path, ProgressEventHandler handler)
    {
        if (apiKey == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("apiKey");
        if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        using (var stream = new ReadOnlyFileStream(path))
        {
            if (handler != null)
            {
                stream.ProgressChanging += handler;
            }

            string fileFormat = TrackFormatDetector.Detect(path);
            if (fileFormat == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidAudioFormatException();
            }

            var dataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            dataContent.Add(new StringContent(apiKey), "api_key");
            dataContent.Add(new StringContent(fileFormat), "filetype");
            dataContent.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "track");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(
                new ProductInfoHeaderValue(new ProductHeaderValue("xxxx", "1.0")));
            HttpResponseMessage response =
                await client.PostAsync(@"http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/upload", dataContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            HttpContent content = response.Content;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                stream.ProgressChanging -= handler;
            }

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                string s = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You *should* move `fileFormat` to parameters, this method is doing too much
- Use [`IProgress<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-5.0) instead of `handler` to properly report progress back to the UI thread (see [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) for examples).
- Add `CancellationToken` parameter if necessary